# Update Data When Trigger Execute in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I want WaterRateMeterStart with WaterRateMeterEnd have same value sequentially if data updated.

[image]

This is my table

[image]

And This is my table structure

[image]

This my code and 
I do not know how mistakes can occur.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_rates_water_again AFTER UPDATE ON waterrates FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF
        new.WaterRateMeterStart <> old.WaterRateMeterStart THEN
            UPDATE waterrates 
            SET WaterRateMeterEnd = new.WaterRateMeterStart 
        WHERE
            WaterRateId = ( new.WaterRateId - 1 );

        ELSEIF new.WaterRateMeterEnd <> old.WaterRateMeterEnd THEN
        UPDATE waterrates 
        SET WaterRateMeterStart = new.WaterRateMeterEnd 
        WHERE
            WaterRateId = ( new.WaterRateId + 1 );

    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And error if I updated the data

```
UPDATE `waterrates` SET `WaterRateMeterStart` = '9' WHERE `waterrates`.`WaterRateId` = 2
```

[image]

Comment: This error is due to a documented restriction in MySQL. It's not possible to run an UPDATE statement on the table within an AFTER UPDATE trigger on the table.

Comment: That means you can't do this with a trigger. You'll have to update both rows with SQL statements executed from your app.

Comment: I tried change my code to UPDATE waterrates SET WaterRateMeterStart = 9; but same error; 
should i use a stored procedure.

Comment: To fix the error, you should do `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_update_rates_water_again`. The trigger is going to throw the error, and cause the triggering statement to fail, whenever the trigger attempts to execute an `UPDATE waterrates` statement.